# Download multiple files from ftp location from ajax call through servlet/java

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have files inside folders at ftp location. I want to download multiple files from web application through ajax call.

Tried one way that copy to server from ftp and converting to zip and then download but i dont want to download to server. Is there anyway i can directly download form ftp.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

[if using apache FTP client on the java server](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String)) you can `retrieveFileStream(path)` and then iterate the inputstream and write to the `HttpServletResponse`